# Firebase authentication issue using AngularJS/AngularFire

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am getting an error response from my firebase when trying to make a registration form to register a user. I am using angularjs and angularfire.

The error I get is:

***The specified authentication provider is not enabled for this Firebase.***

Here is my form:

**Register.html**

```
    <form name="registrationForm" ng-submit="register()" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.firstname" ng-required="true" class="form-control form-control2" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="First Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.lastname" ng-required="true" class="form-control form-control2" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Last Name">
  </div>        
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input ng-model="user.email" ng-required="true" type="email" name="email" class="form-control  form-control2" placeholder="Email">
    <p class="error" ng-show="loginForm.email.$invalid && loginForm.email.$touched">Must be valid email!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input ng-model="user.password" ng-required="true" name="password" type="password" class="form-control  form-control2" placeholder="Password">
    <p class="error" ng-show="loginForm.password.$invalid && loginForm.password.$touched">Must enter a password!</p>
  </div>
  <button ng-disabled="registrationForm.$invalid" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  <p style="margin-top: 5px;">or <span style="font-size: 14px"><a href="#/login">Login</a></span></p>
</form>
```

Here is my registration function that is being called when I submit my form, and what is returning the error on submit:

**Controllers.js**

```
    $scope.register = function() {
    auth.$createUser({
      email: $scope.user.email,
      password: $scope.user.password
    }).then(function(regUser){
      $scope.message = "Hey, " + $scope.user.firstname + ", you're registered!";
    }).catch(function(error){
      $scope.message = error.message;
    });  //create user
  };     //register
```

I made sure to enable email/password authentication in my firebase settings, so I do not know why I am getting this response.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why I was receiving the error. The syntax I used above is only for firebase databases that have been created with the legacy console. In order to enable email/password authentication for the new version of Firebase, you must follow the steps listed [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#before_you_begin)